# Update vector style after adding feature to the map

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

I' adding a `vector` with style (fill color blue) and I want to allow the user to change color of the vector with color picker and jQuery. I searched on Google how to change the fillcolor but I am lost with `DrawFeature`.

```js
vector[i] = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'added Layer',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: href,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),

  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'blue'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      textAlign: 'left',
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      text: title,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
      }),
      font: '11px arial,sans-serif'
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(vector[i]);
```

After `map.addLayer` how can I change style? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```js
var feature = new ol.Feature({
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'red'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      textAlign: 'left',
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      text: "",
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
      }),
      font: '11px arial,sans-serif'
    })
  })
});

vector[i].drawFeature = feature;
```

Comment: I am on OpenLayers 3 and i use ASP.NET + Jquery + SQL Server to show  kml or Geojson

Comment: Do you have draw interaction working? [An example.](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/draw-features.html)

Comment: I found, vector[noDossierCouche].setStyle(styleupdate); -_- no found this on other forum

Comment: You can build a style function and store it, then a second one with your new style, and switch them - `vector.setStyle(style1|style2)